# Having a MYSQL query within a PHP fwrite function

Tags: mysql

basically I am try to get the php file to create another php file which has XHTML, PHP and MYSQL within it. I am trying to include a MYSQL query but the problem is that the apostrophe (') that I use to start the fwrite string get confused when it reaches a MYSQL query because it too also has an apostrophe but I just want that string to continue not end. What should I do for this to work? Thanks in advance for any help.

The code (just the relevant bit):

```
$filename = "websites/".$firstpage.".php";
$filehandle = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("error opening file");
$datawrite = '
$query = "SELECT websitetitle FROM $weblist WHERE webID='$webID'";
$result =  mysql_query ($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo $row['webID'];

';
fwrite($filehandle, $datawrite);

fclose($filehandle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the ' in the query with \'  This will not exec and end the string

```
$filename = "websites/".$firstpage.".php";
$filehandle = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("error opening file");
$datawrite = '
    $query = "SELECT websitetitle FROM $weblist WHERE webID=\'$webID\'";
    $result =  mysql_query ($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

    echo $row[\'webID\'];

';
fwrite($filehandle, $datawrite);

fclose($filehandle);
```

Check this out for reference
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @user1359106 glad that helped... Dont forget to accept the best answer.  Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: Hi, it is outputting the text as I wanted, but it does not seem to actually be looking for the requested information from the database. does the \' make the ' useless for MYSQL? Just wondering what it could be... this is the full PHP and MYSQL bit:

Comment: <?php

// connection details
include("/db_connection.php");

//connection
$dbc = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $password);

//database selection
mysql_select_db ($dbname);

//identify user and site
$weblist= "'.$weblist.'";
$web_number= "'.$webID.'";

//database information retreival

$query = "SELECT websitetitle FROM $weblist WHERE webID=\'$web_number\'";
$result =  mysql_query ($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo $row[\'websitetitle\'];
?>

Answer (score 0):

Just use proper escaping and place a `\` before the apostrophe.

```
$datawrite = '
$query = "SELECT websitetitle FROM $weblist WHERE webID=\'$webID\'";
$result =  mysql_query ($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo $row[\'webID\'];

';
```